# How do I implement asynchronous processing on an apache felix?

Tags: java, asynchronous, osgi, apache-felix, bndtools

In our current project we have the need to do some calculations asynchronously.
We're using OSGi with bndtools on an Apache Felix 4.
Any advice on how to do that?
We're looking for something like http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about OSGi promises

1. OSGi specification [705 Promises Specification](https://osgi.org/download/r6/osgi.cmpn-6.0.0.pdf)
2. excellent presentation on [Asynchronous OSGi](http://www.slideshare.net/mfrancis/asynchronous-osgi-promises-for-the-masses-osgi-devcon-2014) by Tim Ward
3. Interview/Introduction [OSGi Promises specification](https://www.infoq.com/interviews/tim-ward-osgi-promises) also from Tim Ward
4. Code example from  [Apache Aries on Promises](https://aries.apache.org/modules/async-svcs.html)

Comment: Great links. Thank you. Presumably we will use the felix Event mechanism.

Comment: The Event Admin mechanism is not necessarily that useful because it provides no way to send a reply. I assume that you need to get back the results of your calculations? In which case Async Services is the way to go.

Comment: Good to know. As a matter of fact we don't need the result. We trigger our calculations over database entries that have been stored in the database before.
We just don't want to have these calculations synchronously because they would block the storage of future entries.

Comment: Because basically this answer also fits my problem and should be helpful to others, I'll mark it as accepted.